# Can I request that my question (that may lead to a discussion) on StackOverflow be closed without being penalized?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close, penalty

I currently have an open question on StackOverflow: [How can an Android background thread detect if another activity is active and ready to receive data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212273/android-bluetooth-plotting-application-uses-thread-and-activities-incorrectly)

If perhaps the question starts off OK it certainly loses it's focus. I finally end up asking 3 questions at the end. I'm afraid it looks like I'm starting a discussion.

How can I request that this question be closed on StackOverflow without being penalized?

I would then want to post 2 or 3 different questions related to the original post but that are clearer and more specific. There will be some overlap as the new questions have the same background (based on the same project). I hope that's OK.

Comment: You might have to define "penalized." You don't lose any rep if one of your questions is closed, or anything.

Comment: @Popular Demand, I think you know what I mean: lose reputation unnecessarily. I'm watching my rep drop as I wright this comment! But I continue to earned badges!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nobody has provided an answer to [your question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212273/android-bluetooth-plotting-application-uses-thread-and-activities-incorrectly), so I believe you can do the following without confusing folks:

1. Edit this question down to containing only one question.
2. Ask the other one or two questions that remain in one or two additional questions.

Comment: LOL the system tells me I cannot accept your answer unless I wait 6 minutes. I guess they want me to think it over. Funny. But great answer. I will give it a try. And I will be accepting your answer in 6 minutes, no that's 5 minutes now:)

Comment: @Vince: sounds good, @sarnold has sound advice too. I would say as a general rule that if folks aren't participating on your question it is a *good idea* to edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Vince, ah, the single question is definitely more clear. Good work. :) While @sixletter is correct that it is a good idea to edit your question to make it more clear, note that [ten or more edits turns your question or answer into a community wiki entry](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/community-wiki), so try to make each edit _count_.

Comment: Right you are folks. That is what I have done already.

Answer (score 1):

Your three questions seem closely enough related that I don't see any real problem with all three in one *question*, but I might suggest that you edit the post and re-word them a little:

> Discard/buffer all BluetoothData and do not call plotData() if the Plotting Activity is not active?

This question seems to be missing some very important words. :) "Should I?" "Could I?" "How do I?" ...

Comment: thanks! I will keep that in mind next time. For now I chose @sixlettervariables answer.